# Excel macro to rename the file extension

Tags: vba, excel

I am naive to scripts, and I started working with Excel macros. I am looking for a macro to rename only the file extension from *.xml to *.qml. The *.xml file is in the same workbook path. So, I appreciate if anyone could help in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code:

```
Sub RenameFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String, newName As String
    Dim filePath As Variant
    filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    StrFile = Dir(filePath & "*.xml")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        newName = Replace(StrFile, ".xml", ".qml")
        Name filePath & StrFile As filePath & newName
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: Code will rename all `.xml` files to `.qml` so its better to take the back up before executing the code.